# How to new rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I have tried to install ruby on rails on my Ubuntu 12.04.

I am trying to create a new project and everything looks cool

```
 create  
  create  README.rdoc
  create  Rakefile
  create  config.ru
  create  .gitignore
  create  Gemfile
  create  app
  create  app/assets/images/rails.png
  create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
  create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
  create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
  create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
  create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
  create  app/mailers/.gitkeep
  create  app/models/.gitkeep
  create  config
  create  config/routes.rb
  create  config/application.rb
  create  config/environment.rb
  create  config/environments
  create  config/environments/development.rb
  create  config/environments/production.rb
  create  config/environments/test.rb
  create  config/initializers
  create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
  create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
  create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
  create  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
  create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
  create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
  create  config/locales
  create  config/locales/en.yml
  create  config/boot.rb
  create  config/database.yml
  create  db
  create  db/seeds.rb
  create  doc
  create  doc/README_FOR_APP
  create  lib
  create  lib/tasks
  create  lib/tasks/.gitkeep
  create  lib/assets
  create  lib/assets/.gitkeep
  create  log
  create  log/.gitkeep
  create  public
  create  public/404.html
  create  public/422.html
  create  public/500.html
  create  public/favicon.ico
  create  public/index.html
  create  public/robots.txt
  create  script
  create  script/rails
  create  test/fixtures
  create  test/fixtures/.gitkeep
  create  test/functional
  create  test/functional/.gitkeep
  create  test/integration
  create  test/integration/.gitkeep
  create  test/unit
  create  test/unit/.gitkeep
  create  test/performance/browsing_test.rb
  create  test/test_helper.rb
  create  tmp/cache
  create  tmp/cache/assets
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.gitkeep
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.gitkeep
  create  vendor/plugins
  create  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
     run  bundle install --local
```

but the last line has an error

```
/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory -- /usr/bin/bundle (LoadError)
```

After that, I have tried to start the rails server, and again I have error messages

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/mehmet/Desktop/ror/denemeee/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from script/rails:5:in `<main>'
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: did you install the bundler gem ? `gem install bundler` ?

Comment: What installation guide did you follow? can i have the link?

Comment: ror official page, `http://rubyonrails.org/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also experienced problem like this,

If you look at the error message, mostly you can find useful information to help you move forward to the next step

For example in your case 
`require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup

This says they can not find the bundler, at which point, you will fount out that you will need to run this command

```
sudo gem install bundler
```

Without the sudo, you'll probably get an error of permission to write in folders.

Mostly the gems will tell you what to do, so in the later case,

just run

```
sudo bundle install
```

again you can do it with sudo, for permission complains. But I will recommend you to look at rvm, rvmsudo that will help you segment your gem distribution depending of the rail project.

If you are new in rails, maybe I can give you a brief and generic steps, without getting into much details about it, you can google it later for details.

1) First create or load new rails project (At this point you are done)

2) Load the gems and dependencies of the rails project by running following command

```
gem install bundler
```

3) You need to consider, if you are going to work in one project, or different kinds of project. since every project has its own set of gems or dependencies, and the version of the required gem might break the dependency of another rails project. To avoid this I suggest you start looking at rvm and rvmsudo.

At some point you'll wind up doing it anyway, because you will want to work with several rails projects.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you very much for the long answer. I did what you said. But after the command `sudo bundle install` i had this kind of error `Bundler::GemfileNotFound`

Comment: Maybe you are in different path, and Gemfile can not be found. you can run "cd path_of_rails_project", and run gem bundle install